# Can-I assign a value directly to an object?

Tags: vba, class, properties

In VBA, you can use either **Cells** or **Cells.Value**, it has the same effect. Test1 and Test2 behaves the same way, allthough in test 2 the string is passed directly to the object.

```
Sub Test1()
    Cells(1, 1) .Value  = "Hello"
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Cells(1, 2) = "World"
End Sub
```

Is it possible to do something similar with any user class? Can-I assign a value directly to an object created from one of my classes withpout using the property value ?

Comment: When you say "I know that this code is not working", that makes sense but what exactly is happening? Do you have any errors or debug results to share? What happens when you inspect the value of MyVariable after each line of the last few lines?

Comment: You can create a [class module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Error-Codes/program-with-class-modules) and add some public properties to that. Remember in VBA, properties must be declared to be "Read-Only", "Write-Only", or "Read/Write" as determined by the `Let` or `Get` keywords. `Public Property Let MyProp(...)`.

Comment: See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx for how to set a VBA class property as the "default property"

Comment: And to your other question wrt "Adding a Value directly to an object". What you are doing here is assign a value to a _default property_. VBA doesn't have a built-in way to accomplish this from the IDE, but there [is a hack](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/694992-how-declare-default-property-class-module) that you can try. I've never tested this because I generally prefer to be explicit when assigning values.

Comment: ...will not work for a Type/Struct (which is not an object) though, so not possible for your specific example.  You'd need to make that a class.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your link, thats exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Following Tim and K. recommendations, I've created a the following class:

```
Option Explicit
Dim LNG_Debut As Long

Public Property Let Debut(tLNG_Debut As Long)
    LNG_Debut = tLNG_Debut
End Property

Property Get Debut() As Long
    Debut = LNG_Debut
End Property
```

Then, I’ve exported that class to notepad and modified it the following way:

```
Property Get Debut() As Long
    Attribute Debut.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Debut = LNG_Debut
End Property
```

And finaly, I’ve imported it back in the VBA editor.
Then, both Test1 and Test2 have the same result

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim MyVariable As obj_Test
    Set MyVariable = New obj_Test
    MyVariable.Debut = 10

End Sub
```

And

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim MyVariable As obj_Test
    Set MyVariable = New obj_Test
    MyVariable = 10

End Sub
```

Many thanks